# How does the Blowfish algorithm key initialization work

Tags: encryption, blowfish

I'm having some trouble understanding the Blowfish encryption algorithm.  From the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_%28cipher%29#The_algorithm)...

> The secret key is then, byte by byte, cycling the key if necessary, XORed with all the P-entries in order

Can someone explain this in more detail?  For example, the first few P entries are 0x243f6a88, 0x85a308d3, 0x13198a2e, 0x03707344,...

Supposing the secret key is `abcd`, how would I implement this part of the algorithm?

Comment: Definitely too many commas in that sentence...

Comment: dude let me tell a thing or two. First find a source code for blowfish.h. i got my header file from https://defuse.ca/blowfish.htm blowfish.h is in c++. it contains a lot of data. not sure if it will make blowish algorithm any clearer but it provides some useful tips, you can modify the code itself ofc. i am not sure how secure this implementation is but atleast it does the job in terms of encrypting and decrypting string.

Comment: If you think the code behind the link answers the question, please at least quote that part in the answer. Link-only answers can become useless if the link breaks. (Also, it would be preferable if you could answer in words rather than code.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quoted passage of the Wikipedia article <strike>is wrong</strike> does not at first reading seem to match Blowfish as in Bruce Schneier's *Description of a new variable-length key, 64-bit block cipher (Blowfish)* ([in proceedings of the first FSE conference, held Dec. 1993](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-58108-1_24)) which for this same operation reads:

> XOR P<sub>1</sub> with the first 32 bits of the key, XOR P<sub>2</sub> with the second 32-bits of the key, and so on for all bits of the key (possibly up to P<sub>14</sub>). Repeatedly cycle through the key bits until the entire P-array has been XORed with key bits. (For every short key, there is at least one equivalent longer key; for example, if A is a 64-bit key, then AA, AAA, etc., are equivalent keys.)

In C++, if `P` and `key` are arrays of 32-bit words, and `keylen` (from 1 to 14) is the key size in 32-bit increments, this can be implemented as shown in the wikipedia article:

```
for (int i=0 ; i<18 ; ++i)
   P[i] ^= key[i % keylen];
```

Customarily conversion of key bytes to the array `key`, and constants for initialization of `P`, is [big-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) (as traditional in cryptography for many things such as DES, RSA, SHA, AES, but not MD5).

Many actual implementations of Blowfish accept keys with size any multiple of 8-bit, and there's nothing in Bruce Schneier's description to forbid that. To cover this, if `P` is an array of 32-bit words, `key` is an array of 8-bit bytes, and `keylen` is the key size (from 4 to 56) in 8-bit increments, the loop can become, on an big endian machine:

```
for (int i=0 ; i<72; ++i)
   ((uint8_t*)P)[i] ^= key[i % keylen];
```

or, to keep the code endian-neutral:

```
for (unsigned i=0 ; i<72; ++i)
   P[i>>2] ^= ((uint32_t)key[i % keylen])<<((3&~i)<<3);
```

Note: the shift count computed as `(3&~i)<<3` is 24, 16, 8, 0, 24, 16, 8, 0, 24.. when `i` is 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8..

**Note**: while Blowfish's definition states a minimum key size of 32 bits, some implementations lower that to 8 bits, including the one that was used for these [test vectors of Blowfish with variable key length](https://web.archive.org/web/20011115092753/http://www.counterpane.com/vectors.txt) (also [available as a C header](https://web.archive.org/web/20011115092753/http://www.counterpane.com/vectors2.txt)). Further, some implementations (especially of Blowfish as used in [Bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)) allow up to 576-bit keys (72 bytes), rather than 448-bit (56 bytes).

---

Example 1: if the key is the string `abcd` in ASCII, the array `key` (viewed as a 32-bit array) is the single element `0x61626364;` thus after processing the key,
`P[ 0]` is `0x243F6A88^0x61626364` that is `0x455D09EC`,
`P[ 1]` is `0x85A308D3^0x61626364` that is `0xE4C16BB7`,..
`P[17]` is `0x8979FB1B^0x61626364` that is `0xE81B987F`.

Example 2: if the key is the string `abcdJKL` in ASCII, after processing the key,
`P[ 0]` is `0x243F6A88^0x61626364` that is `0x455D09EC`,
`P[ 1]` is `0x85A308D3^0x4A4B4C61` that is `0xCFE844B2`,..
`P[17]` is `0x8979FB1B^0x4B4C6162` that is `0xC2359A79`.

Note: there are further transformations of `P` but they are rather unambiguous; refer to either of the articles.

---

**Final Caution**: some Blowfish implementations (especially those used in Bcrypt) are known to vary in how they convert text to bytes before applying the above transformation of key to `P`; some bugs have even crept there, for [example](https://www.mindrot.org/files/jBCrypt/internat.adv)

> Versions of jBCrypt before 0.3 suffered from a bug related to character encoding that substantially reduced the entropy of hashed passwords containing non US-ASCII characters. An incorrect encoding step transparently replaced such characters by `?` prior to hashing. In the worst case of a password consisting solely of non-US-ASCII characters, this would cause its hash to be equivalent to all other such passwords of the same length.

Notice that if "*of the same length*" is necessary in this quotation, then some length, padding or terminating character must have been included in the key converted to bytes (otherwise all passwords consisting solely of non-US-ASCII characters would have been equivalent, regardless of length).

Comment: Probably the best answer I've gotten in any stackexchange site.  The examples really help clarify things for me.

Comment: @Ben: unfortunately this answer is not enough to fully cover the variations found in the field; see new Final Caution!